# Linear independence of the linear functionals $\phi_k(p)=\int_{-1}^{1}x^kp(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $V=P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the polynomials  with degree $ \leq n$, define  $\phi_k, k=0,1,2, \ldots ,n$, linear functionals such that:
$$\phi_k(p)=\int_{-1}^1 x^kp(x)\mathrm{d}x, \ \ \forall p \in V.$$
Prove that $B=\{\phi_0,\phi_1, \ldots , \phi_n\}$ is a basis of $V^\star$ (the dual space).
I have tried to prove the linear independence writing down a general expression for the polynomial $p$, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to show is that for constants $a_k$, $\sum_k a_k \phi_k = 0$ if and only if $a_k = 0$ for all $k$. Clearly if the constants are zero, it holds. Suppose now that $\sum_k a_k \phi_k = 0$ for some $k$, meaning that for any polynomial $p$,

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k p(x)\,dx = 0.$$

Let us let $q(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k$. This defines a polynomial. What happens if you take $p=q$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_k\lambda_k\phi_k = 0$ then $\int_{-1}^1\left(\sum_k\lambda_kx^k\right)p(x)\,dx = 0$ for all $p\in P_n$. Now, choose $p(x) = \sum_k\lambda_kx^k$.